# Informix - extract day of month from date, and select only odd days

Tags: sql, informix

how to extract day of month from date, and select only odd days in Informix SQL?

Answer (score 3):

Day of month is simply the `DAY(date_or_datetime_column)` function, related to the `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions. Getting only odd numbers is done with a simple modulo 2 expression.

So I think you only need:

```
SELECT date_col, DAY(date_col)
  FROM table
  WHERE MOD(DAY(date_col), 2) = 1
```

Hope that's useful.